# Could program classified as a virus have a security flaw?

Tags: c++, virus

I was extremely surprised to find that my AV program (from my ISP, based on Kapersky) detected one of my C++ programs (i.e. test.exe) as having a virus.  The code was generated from Visual Studio 2010 using the Debug configuration (surprisingly, the release version didn't have a virus).  The reported virus was "Gen:Variant.Symmi.3690", which resulted in a complete dead end for any Google searches.

However, it got me thinking that my program might have some sort of security flaw (e.g. buffer overrun) that the AV tool believes is capable of being exploited.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

This sort of thing happens every now and again. It's just a false positive rather than anything flawed in your program. By chance your compiled program has something in common with the signature used by your AV tool to identify that virus. What you should do is send your program to the AV vendor so that they can fix their signatures.

AV software does not attempt to detect security flaws like buffer overruns. If they did, and could do so effectively, then almost all software would be detected as malware!

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happens, it's called false positive. On [virus total](https://www.virustotal.com/) you can see witch AV classify your program as a virus.